# Find integral value using MC method

Tags: r, statistics, montecarlo, integral

I have a homework in a subject called 'Monthe-Carlo methods' and I'm stuck with one task.

> The task is as follows:
>   Using MC method find an approximate value of the integral (see the pic below),
>    where D is an area [0 to infinity) x [0 to infinity) x [0 to infinity).
>   Also, find the error value for probability 0,99.

[Integral pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWoEE.png)

What I've done so far, is in the code below.

The main question that I have, is .. Which distribution should I choose for generated values? And what's the core logic behind it?
At the moment I used just plain normal distribution with parameters (0,1) just to get some initial results, but as the results show, the error value is really big and therefore it's could not be the best solution..

Thanks in advance!

```
n <- 100000
alfa <- 0.01 # 1-0.99
# võtame generaatori preagu normaaljaotusest, sest integraalfunktsiooni kuju on üsnagi sarnane 
# normaaljaotuse tihedusfunktsioonile

# gen <- function(n){
#   return(matrix(runif(3*n, 0, Inf),ncol=3))
# }
gen <- function(n){
  return(matrix(rnorm(3*n, 0, 1),ncol=3))
}

g <- function(x){
  #tihedus <- dunif(x[,1],0,Inf)*dunif(x[,2],0,Inf)*dunif(x[,3],0,Inf)
  tihedus <- rnorm(x[,1],0,1)*rnorm(x[,2],0,1)*rnorm(x[,3],0,1)
  return( (x[,1]+x[,2])*exp(-(x[,1]+x[,2]+2*x[,3]))/(x[,1]^2+x[,2]+x[,3]+1) / tihedus*((x[,1]>=0) + (x[,2]>=0) + (x[,3]>=0)) )
}
MC(gen, g, n, alfa)
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible; what and where is function `MC`?

Comment: Exponential, of course, you should use exponential distribution

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux, yea, that's what I thought myself actually. But what about the rate of it? the parameter ..

Comment: ?!? What about 1, 1, 1/2 ?